# uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation. why?

Tags: c, initialization, allocation

After running Valgrind on my code I got an error:

```
uninitialized value was created by a heap allocation.
```

My code:

```
void adicionaHashtag(char* x){
    char*y=malloc(sizeof(x));/***ERROR IS HERE***/
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(x); i++){
        y[i]=tolower(x[i]);
    }

    Lista_Hashtags*aux = (Lista_Hashtags*)malloc(sizeof(Lista_Hashtags));
    strcpy(aux->nome, y);
    aux->contador=1;
    if(contador_unitario == 0){
        ultimo = aux;
    }
    contador_unitario++;
    aux->proximo = primeiro;
    primeiro = aux;
}
```

any tips?

also, what does "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" mean?
~

Comment: Use of `sizeof(x)` is incorrect there . Allocate memory equal to `strlen(x)+1` to `y` .

Comment: Also, don't forget to add `\0` to `y` or `strcpy` will have problems.

Comment: sorry in advance for the "noob" question. How exacly should I add \0 to y? strcpy is indeed giving trouble. @Johny Mopp

Comment: Ok! I changed it, but the error doesn't seem to be resolved.. thanks for the tip though. @ameyCU

Comment: `char* y = strdup(x);` would have prevented both of these problems. Some people might argue that it would be less efficient (going over the string twice - once to copy `x`, then again to convert to lowercase), but unless we're talking about huge strings being processed many times, the overhead is probably worthwhile: making the code simpler and more obviously correct for what's probably minuscule runtime cost..

Comment: Another possibility for some of the valgrind messages might be that the argument `x` isn't being passed a valid string.  If the suggestions here don't solve your problem there might also be a problem at the location(s) where `adicionaHashtag()` is called.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks a lot Michael! "strdup" did indeed help!! Thanks again my friend, a good one!

Comment: Also, `strcpy(aux->nome, y);` looks like a potential problem.  I wouldn't be surprised if it should be `aux->nome = y;`, but that really depends on what type `Lista_Hashtags.nome` is.  If it's a `char*` then you want `aux->nome = y`, if it's a `char[]` then you want something like `strcpy()`, but you may need to protect against buffer overrun.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ok Michael! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"uninitialized value ..."
You may use `char*y=calloc(strlen(x),0);` instead of `char*y=malloc(sizeof(x));`.Initialize the memory with "0".

Comment: Or you can initialize the memory after allocating it. All-bits-zero may or may not be a valid initial value. For example, null pointers are usually represented as all-bits-zero, but that's not actually guaranteed.

Comment: size needs +1 for the null terminator

Comment: @KeithThompson all bits zero is valid for `char` as it is an integer type

Comment: @M.M: Yes, but we don't know what's in `Lista_Hashtags` -- though now that I look at it, it's the first `malloc` that's apparently the problem. On the other hand, if an allocated array of `char` is going to hold a string, there's no need to zero all of it.

Comment: Yet another example of an allocation for a string that is too small for the terminating null.  Please - can people just start using `strdup()` so we can stop seeing this bug over and over?

Answer (score 0):

```
void adicionaHashtag(char* x){
    char*y=malloc(sizeof(x));/***ERROR IS HERE***/
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(x); i++){
        y[i]=tolower(x[i]);
    }
```

You're trying to allocate and initialize a string with a copy of the string pointed to by `x`.

`sizeof(x)` is the size of a `char*` pointer.  That's typically 4 or 8 bytes. You need to allocate enough space to hold the string itself.

```
char *y = malloc(strlen(x) + 1);
```

The `+ 1` is to allow for the terminating null character `'\0'`.

Calling `strlen` on each iteration of the loop is inefficient, but not incorrect; I'll leave that for now. There's a potential problem if any of the copied characters have negative values (an unfortunate characteristic of the `tolower()` function. The assignment should be:

```
y[i] = tolower((unsigned char)x[i]);
```

Finally, let's say `x` points to the string `"hello"`. You're correctly copying 5 characters -- but not the final `'\0'`. One possible fix is to change the `<` in the loop condition to `<=`, which will copy characters 0 through 5 rather than 0 through 4.

But you can just use the existing `strcpy` function, which handles all this for you (and more efficiently):

```
char *y = malloc(strlen(x) + 1);
strcpy(y, x);
```

(You should also check the value returned by `malloc`, and treat it as an error if it's `NULL`.)

For that matter, you probably don't need `y` at all.  `x` is already a pointer to a string. You copy it into the memory allocated for `y`, and then you copy that into `aux->nome`. Unless there's more code you haven't shown us that uses `y`, this is unnecessary (and a memory leak!).  You can drop the declaration of `y` and the code that initializes it, and just copy from `x` directly:

```
Lista_Hashtags *aux = malloc(sizeof *aux);
strcpy(aux->nome, x);
```

(This assumes that `aux->nome` is an array, not a pointer, and that it's big enough to hold a copy of the string.)

(Note that I've changed your `malloc` call to a simpler and more robust form.)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Note that `strdup` is non-standard.